# Why does JQM lose the viewport within a fixed toolbars multipage setup?

Tags: jquery, html, css, jquery-mobile, layout

I need to build a functionality to select a category out of 300 available categories within 3 levels using jQuery Mobile.

The code works somehow, but the first load shows a layout problem where the listview ist not positioned properly. Here is the example in jsfiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/x_merlin_x/esb6j7wa/5/ Once you click on the first menu item the submenu loads in the correct position. Also the lower menu disapears in chrome (not in jsfiddle), once you click the left top menu icon and does not apear again until reloaded.

Code:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="DE">
<head>
    <meta HTTP-EQUIV="Content-Type" CONTENT="text/html; charset=utf-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">       
     <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquerymobile/1.4.5/jquery.mobile.min.css"/>
     <style>
      #navpanel{
        background-color: #4f4f4f;
        width:200px;
      }
      #navpanel ul{
        width: 200px;
          padding: 0;
          list-style: none;
          list-style-image: none;
          color: white;
          text-shadow: 0 0px 0;
      }
      #navpanel li{
        margin:10px;
        padding:10px;
          border-bottom: 1px solid dimgray;
          text-shadow: 0 0px 0;
      }
      #navpanel li a:link,
      #navpanel li a:visited{
          text-decoration: none;
          color: white;
          font-weight: normal;
      }
    </style>
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.3/jquery.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquerymobile/1.4.5/jquery.mobile.min.js"></script>
    <script>
     $(function(){
          $( "[data-role='header'], [data-role='footer']" ).toolbar();
      });

      $(function() {
        $( "body>[data-role=\'panel\']" ).panel();
      });
    </script>
  </head>
  <body>
    <div data-role="header" data-tap-toggle="false" data-fullscreen="true" data-position="fixed" class="fixedHeader">
        <a class="" style="margin-top:2px;" href="#navpanel">&#9776;</a>
    </div>
    <div data-role="page" id="select_maincat">  
        <div data-role="content"> 
          <h1>Wählen Sie eine Kategorie aus</h1>
            <ul data-role="listview">
               <li><a href="#dienstleistungen">Dienstleistungen</a></li>
            </ul>     
        </div>
    </div>
    <div data-role="page" id="dienstleistungen">  
        <div data-role="content"> 
          <h1>Wählen Sie eine Kategorie aus</h1>
            <ul data-role="listview">    
              <li><a href="#betreuung-pflege">Betreuung & Pflege</a></li>
            </ul>     
        </div>
    </div>
    <div data-role="footer" data-position="fixed" data-tap-toggle="false">
      footer
      <div data-role="navbar" style="border-bottom: 1px solid #1F1F1F;">
        <ul>
            <li><a href="" data-icon="home" data-theme="b" data-ajax="false">home</a></li>
        </ul>
      </div>
    <!-- /navbar -->
  </div> 
  <!-- footer -->
  <div data-role="panel" id="navpanel" data-display="overlay" data-position="right">
      <ul>
          <li><a href="/" data-ajax="false">test</a></li>
      </ul>
  </div>
  </body>
</html>
```

Unfortunately there is no error message or any indication that could help me fix this.

Comment: remove `data-fullscreen="true"` https://jsfiddle.net/Palestinian/esb6j7wa/7/

Comment: This interestingly fixes the problem with the category layout, but the lower menu still disapears. There must be something else wrong as once I click on the menu icon, the layout changes to 440px x 870px inside google chrome developer tools simulating iPhone 6. This therefore moves the menu out of the viewport.